# Extending the DrawingView frame has some issues in iOS

Tags: ios, drawing, core-graphics

I am implementing drawing in iphone, and my drawing works perfectly, I have provided the user a drawingView of size (315x95) and below this drawingView their is a image which of size (320x100). This is the default View which user sees and he can draw only in that View.

Now what I have done is provided a button at one corner of the drawingView , so on click of which the user can increase the drawingView if he/she wants to write more and again their is button at the bottom of this extended View to decrease the view to its original position.

Now , my problems are

1) when I draw in default size and click on the button to extend , the drawn Image gets stretched to extended frame, which I dont want, becuase I am creating extra space for use to right so stretching is of no use

2) when I extend the drawingView and draw something at the bottom, and then click the button to decrease the View, the drawn part at the bottom still remains at the bottom only and is visible.Actually it should get hidden when the drawingView frame is decreased and should be seen when the drawingView frame is increased.

So friends, how can I solve this issue,please help me out

Regards
Ranjit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number 1 sounds like a content mode issue, but number 2 is the result of your views not clipping their subviews properly (or the layer not being clipped to its bounds).  There are properties like `clipsToBounds` and `clipsSubviews` that will come in handy.